# XMLHttpRequest with modified Accept header in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I am incorporating a DOI-to-formatted citation feature in my Chrome extension. dx.doi.org [introduced content negotiation](http://www.crossref.org/CrossTech/2011/11/turning_dois_into_formatted_ci.html) about one year ago to support this kind of activity.

I noticed some odd behavior in Chrome when I performed cross-domain XMLHttpRequest with a modified Accept header.  Below is a minimal example of the function that reproduces the issue (jQuery used below, but exact same behavior noticed with XMLHttpRequest):

```
function getCitation() {
var resolveUrl = "http://dx.doi.org/10.2331/suisan.32.804";
var content = 'text/bibliography; style=bibtex; locale=en-US';

document.getElementById("notify").innerHTML = "Loading...";

var jqxhr = jQuery.ajax({
    url: resolveUrl,
    headers: { Accept: content },
    dataType: "text",
    type: "GET"
});
jqxhr.done(function() {
    document.getElementById("notify").innerHTML = jqxhr.responseText;
});
jqxhr.error(function() {
    document.getElementById("notify").innerHTML = "No citation found";
});
}
```

Some extra info: *.doi.org and *.crossref.org permissions are defined in the manifest.

The function works fine and returns the citation for 10.2331/suisan.32.804 in BibTeX format for the en-US locale. The problem arises when I visit http://dx.doi.org/10.2331/suisan.32.804 in any Chrome tab after running this function (not through the extension, I really mean pasting the url in the omnibox). The site returns a 406 error (Accept header request not accepted). If I try once more, the page loads. Then, the real kicker is that after the page loads successfully, the XMLHttpRequest no longer succeeds. So apparently, my header alteration is globally affecting Chrome and isn't limited to my extension's sandbox. I ended up resolving the issue by changing the GET request to POST and everything functions as desired.

If you're really interested in seeing this behavior first hand, I packaged a minimal example extension: [citeTest.crx](http://web.missouri.edu/~mdmnq5/comp/citeTest.crx) (35KB)

Now for my questions:

1. GET: When I make this XMLHttpRequest, is *text/bibliography; style=bibtex; locale=en-US* supposed to be attached to the Accept header outside of my extension? (am I committing some form of bad programming?)
2. GET: Each time I make this XMLHttpRequest, is *text/bibliography; style=bibtex; locale=en-US* being appended, so eventually the Accept header gets really really long? A problem I have is that the style and locale settings may change each time the request is made, so I can't set it just once.
3. POST: The problem I described only occurs with GET requests. Could this problem similarly surface if a user tries to submit a POST based form on dx.doi.org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I think I've gotten to the bottom of this. The problem surfaced because of caching. When the Accept header was set to text/bibliography, requests were redirected to data.crossref.og (or data.datacite.org) because that's where non-text/html content negotiations are handled. When I later made a request with Accept: text/html, the request was still pointed to data.crossref.org (or data.datacite.org) because of caching. The problem is that data.crossref.org and data.datacite.org do not process text/html, only dx.doi.org handles those requests, so they were returning error 406.

In sum, simply adding cache:false to jQuery.ajax allows me to use GET requests just fine. My questions about headers are mostly irrelevant.